How to Close Previously Opened Dropdowns in MudBlazor NavMenu Using JavaScript?
I'm using MudBlazor for my navigation menu, and I need to implement functionality where opening one dropdown automatically closes any previously opened dropdowns. The solution should be implemented purely using JavaScript and HTML. Below is my current code:
<MudNavMenu>
    <MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle2" Color="Color.Inherit" Class="ml-4 my-3"></MudText>
    @foreach (var item in BuildNavMenu())
    {
        if (item.Children.Any())
        {
            <MudNavGroup Title="@item.Title" IconColor="@item.IconColor" Icon="@item.Icon" HideExpandIcon="false" Id="navGroup_@item.Title.Replace(" ", "_")">
                @foreach (var child in item.Children)
                {
                    <MudNavLink Href="@child.Href" IconColor="@child.IconColor" Icon="@child.Icon">@child.Title</MudNavLink>
                }
            </MudNavGroup>
        }
        else
        {
            <MudNavLink Href="@item.Href" IconColor="@item.IconColor" Icon="@item.Icon">@item.Title</MudNavLink>
        }
    }
</MudNavMenu>

@code {
    public class NavItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Href { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public Color IconColor { get; set; }
        public List<NavItem> Children { get; set; } = new List<NavItem>();
    }

    private List<NavItem> BuildNavMenu()
    {
        return new List<NavItem>
        {
            new NavItem
            {
                Title = "Home",
                Href = "/",
                Icon = Icons.Material.TwoTone.Home,
                IconColor = Color.Inherit
            },
            new NavItem
            {
                Title = "Reports",
                Icon = Icons.Material.TwoTone.Description,
                IconColor = Color.Secondary,
                Children = new List<NavItem>
                {
                    new NavItem { Title = "Sales", Href = "/reports/sales", Icon = Icons.Material.TwoTone.TrendingUp, IconColor = Color.Secondary },
                    new NavItem { Title = "Expenses", Href = "/reports/expenses", Icon = Icons.Material.TwoTone.MoneyOff, IconColor = Color.Secondary }
                }
            },
            new NavItem
            {
                Title = "Settings",
                Icon = Icons.Material.TwoTone.Settings,
                IconColor = Color.Info,
                Children = new List<NavItem>
                {
                    new NavItem { Title = "Profile", Href = "/settings/profile", Icon = Icons.Material.TwoTone.Person, IconColor = Color.Info },
                    new NavItem { Title = "Security", Href = "/settings/security", Icon = Icons.Material.TwoTone.Security, IconColor = Color.Info }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const navGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.mud-nav-group');
        navGroups.forEach(group => {
            group.addEventListener('click', function () {
                navGroups.forEach(g => {
                    if (g !== group) {
                        g.classList.remove('mud-expand-icon');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>


Additionally, is there any way to achieve this functionality within MudNavBar and MudNavGroup components natively in MudBlazor? I've tried adding event listeners to manage the dropdowns, but it's not working as expected. Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

You need to use the Expanded bindings on the MudNavGroup.

Note that this will work for the two levels you have.  If you go deeper you'll need more logic to keep the parent nodes open.

First you need to add some functionality to NavItem to track state.  A Guid to identify each item and a bool Expanded state.
    public class NavItem
    {
        public Guid Uid { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Href { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public Color IconColor { get; set; }
        public List<NavItem> Children { get; set; } = new List<NavItem>();
        public bool Expanded;
    }

Add in a page Guid to track the expanded item:
    private Guid _expandedUid;

I've refactored your item generator to get once on component creation:
    private List<NavItem> _navItems = BuildNavMenu();

    private static List<NavItem> BuildNavMenu()
    {
        return new List<NavItem>
        //...
     }


An OnExpanded UI event handler:
    private void OnExpanded(bool expand, Guid uid)
    {
        // We are collapsing the curent node, so there are no expanded nodes
        if (!expand && _expandedUid == uid)
            _expandedUid = Guid.Empty;

        // We are expanding a node so save it to the currently expanded node
        if (expand)
            _expandedUid = uid;

        this.SetExpandedNode();
    }

And a recursive iterator to find and set the expanded node in _navItems.
    private void SetExpandedNode()
    {
        SetExpandedNode(_navItems);
    }

    private void SetExpandedNode(List<NavItem> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            item.Expanded = item.Uid == _expandedUid;

            this.SetExpandedNode(item.Children);
        }
    }

And finally update the MudNavGroup component:
<MudNavGroup Title="@item.Title" 
     IconColor="@item.IconColor" 
     Icon="@item.Icon" 
     Expanded="item.Expanded" 
     ExpandedChanged="(value) => this.OnExpanded(value, item.Uid)" 
     HideExpandIcon="false">

The complete component:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom="true">Hello, world!</MudText>
<MudText Class="mb-8">Welcome to your new app, powered by MudBlazor and the .NET 8 Template!</MudText>

<MudNavMenu>
    <MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle2" Color="Color.Inherit" Class="ml-4 my-3"></MudText>
    @foreach (var item in _navItems)
    {
        if (item.Children.Any())
        {
            <MudNavGroup Title="@item.Title" IconColor="@item.IconColor" Icon="@item.Icon" Expanded="item.Expanded" ExpandedChanged="(value) => this.OnExpanded(value, item.Uid)" HideExpandIcon="false">
                @foreach (var child in item.Children)
                {
                    <MudNavLink Href="@child.Href" IconColor="@child.IconColor" Icon="@child.Icon">@child.Title</MudNavLink>
                }
            </MudNavGroup>
        }
        else
        {
            <MudNavLink Href="@item.Href" IconColor="@item.IconColor" Icon="@item.Icon">@item.Title</MudNavLink>
        }
    }
    </MudNavMenu>

    @code {
    private List<NavItem> _navItems = BuildNavMenu();
    private Guid _expandedUid;

    public class NavItem
    {
        public Guid Uid { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Href { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public Color IconColor { get; set; }
        public List<NavItem> Children { get; set; } = new List<NavItem>();
        public bool Expanded;
    }

    private void OnExpanded(bool expand, Guid uid)
    {
        // We are collapsing the curent node, so there are no expanded nodes
        if (!expand && _expandedUid == uid)
            _expandedUid = Guid.Empty;

        // We are expanding a node so save it to the currently expanded node
        if (expand)
            _expandedUid = uid;

        this.SetExpandedNode();
    }

    private void SetExpandedNode()
    {
        SetExpandedNode(_navItems);
    }

    private void SetExpandedNode(List<NavItem> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            item.Expanded = item.Uid == _expandedUid;

            this.SetExpandedNode(item.Children);
        }
    }

    private static List<NavItem> BuildNavMenu()
    {
        return new List<NavItem>
        {
            new NavItem
            {
                Title = "Home",
                Href = "/",
                Icon = Icons.Material.TwoTone.Home,
                IconColor = Color.Inherit
            },
            new NavItem
            {
                Title = "Reports",
                Icon = Icons.Material.TwoTone.Description,
                IconColor = Color.Secondary,
                Children = new List<NavItem>
                {
                    new NavItem { Title = "Sales", Href = "/reports/sales", Icon = Icons.Material.TwoTone.TrendingUp, IconColor = Color.Secondary },
                    new NavItem { Title = "Expenses", Href = "/reports/expenses", Icon = Icons.Material.TwoTone.MoneyOff, IconColor = Color.Secondary }
                }
            },
            new NavItem
            {
                Title = "Settings",
                Icon = Icons.Material.TwoTone.Settings,
                IconColor = Color.Info,
                Children = new List<NavItem>
                {
                    new NavItem { Title = "Profile", Href = "/settings/profile", Icon = Icons.Material.TwoTone.Person, IconColor = Color.Info },
                    new NavItem { Title = "Security", Href = "/settings/security", Icon = Icons.Material.TwoTone.Security, IconColor = Color.Info }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

